# pdftk, tempfile and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdftk, temporary-files

Ok, I've tried all kinds of stuff and I'm not entirely sure this will work. The pdfs I need to merge are on the server and the links to them are hardcoded. pdftk works locally in my terminal, but not with these remote links. So I'm unsure if this will work once I get it up to production.

Basically, I'm trying to write a method that will retrieve a selected group of pdfs and merge them into one pdf for the user to download.

But I'm having a hard time deciphering how to utilize tempfiles and running terminal commands through the rails app.

Here is the method:

```
def create
@routes = TransitRoute.find(params[:selected_routes])
@selected_routes = @routes.collect {|x| x.new_pdf_link + " "}
Tempfile.open('prefix', "#{Rails.root}/tmp") do |f|
    f.print("pdftk #{@selected_routes} cat output temporary.pdf")
    f.flush
    f.read
  end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
end
```

I have a couple questions:

1. My tempfile has the correct command line written to it:

   pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat output new.pdf

How do I get this line run so that the new.pdf is created?

1. Am I supposed to replace the tempfile with the new pdf, or write the new pdf to it or just make the new pdf in it's own location? If the latter, how do I get it to be temporary?
2. How do I get a link to the new pdf so users can download it?

Some of this may be basic stuff, but I've never had to mess with tempfiles of making pdfs dynamically like this.

Oh yeah, and this app is also in Rails 2.3

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have it working. Here's the new code incase someone has advice for improvement or has the same question:

```
def create
 file = Tempfile.new('temp_route_pdf', "#{Rails.root}/tmp/")
 @routes = TransitRoute.find(params[:selected_routes])
 selected_routes = @routes.collect {|x| x.new_pdf_link + " "}
 route_names = @routes.collect {|x| x.short_name + "_"}
 @generated_pdf_file = "#{route_names}routes.pdf"
 `pdftk #{selected_routes}cat output #{file.path}`
 raise Exception unless $?.success?
 send_file( "#{file.path}",
       :type => "application/pdf",
       :filename => "#{@generated_pdf_file}",
       :disposition => 'inline')
end
```